How should I go about handling multiple phone resolutions from a reference resolution?
I built my entire game in Unity based on my Android phone resolution, both for UI and object sizes. Now, everything looks good for a 1080 x 2400 resolution, but I know that's not the aspect ratio of most phones.
I know scaling for multiple resolutions is a common issue, but I'm looking for simple solution to scale objects and UI elements from my current resolution. My canvases are set to "Screen Space - Camera".
Is there a simple way to do this for all portrait mode resolution or should I just define the objects positions and scales for all the most common resolutions ?

I have done this myself by building to an average resolution (I choose standard 1920x1080 landscape) and having unity auto-resize the canvasses. I have created a script to modify canvasses that look weird on specific resolutions, manually adjusting them how I want them to be.

In your opinion, should I just get all my transforme, divide them by my current resolution and multiply them by the user résolution to just scale everything relative to the screen résolution of the user ? Or do you have a better solution to give me ?

It depends on what outcome you want. Try editing your question to show a screenshot of your game in its reference resolution, and an example of how you want it to look in another resolution. Once we understand the scaling logic you want, we can help you implement it. The reason there's no "just do the right thing automatically" checkbox in Unity is because "the right thing" for your game might be wrong for someone else's, so we need to apply some case-by-case logic to suit the needs of your specific game.


First of all, it is probably best to do a research on which screen resolutions are  common, and use the most common one as the reference resolution. Another approach is to do even more research and use "the next-gen resolution"  (the one that most likely will be the most common one tomorrow).

UI alone can be automatically scaled by setting Canvas Scaler's UI Scale Mode to Scale With Screen Size, Reference Resolution to 1080 x 2400 (or the one you decide to use instead), and Match to 0.5. This doesn't guarantee you the best result right away, but you can tweak the UI to make it look okay on any screen size.
But you also mentioned "objects", which I assume aren't UI. So there's another common approach for that.

To handle both UI and "objects" (or "world", as they are in world space, be they 2d or 3d), you set up the Canvas Scaler pretty much the same way as in 1. but instead of using 0.5 for Match you choose either width (0) or height (1). That chosen dimension will look the same on every screen size. For portrait it is usually width, but really depends on how you designed your game screens. Then, you should scale the world to look good for that chosen dimension. The second dimension, on the other hand, scales with the screen size and you need to test on the smallest and largest aspect ratios you target (can be done in Unity using the Device Simulator) and then adjust your UI to look good for these two, and for most common resolutions, obviously. Also check your world on your smallest aspect ratio, it should fully fit onto the screen. Other than that, the world stays as is except maybe the backgrounds, which you may need to make larger to cover the largest screens, or even move them to UI for proper scaling. Also, it is possible to use the Scroll View for shorter screens. Can work for some games.

Using multiple layouts is also possible, but the necessity of it depends on whether you are happy with the result you achieve in 2. or not, or whether you simply want custom screens. E.g. I once worked on a project that supported phones in portrait and tablets in landscape and layouts were significantly different (one column two tabs and two columns single tab respectively). I also created a tool to handle multiple layouts as different scenes in my early days with Unity. I archived it on GitHub as now I'm not happy with how I designed it, but you can still use its code as a reference for your better system, if you decide to go with this approach.

Besides the aspect ratio, you also have to properly handle screens that are partially covered by e.g. camera or other tools manufacturers put into screens, you have to handle screens that have rounded edges etc. For that Unity offers Screen.safeArea. The common approach is having a background that covers the whole screen (i.e. doesn't respect safe area) but display all the interactable objects (both world & UI) within the bounds of safe area.


P.S. I don't exactly remember whether using  "Screen Space - Camera" has any potential pitfalls. So you will have to figure that out yourself. And just in case, it is absolutely normal to have multiple canvases with different settings.
